# Aggravating and summarizing data in SharePoint list view

Tags: listview, loops, sharepoint, aggregate-functions

I have a list in SharePoint showing people and the projects they are working on with the project duration and amount of effort: (see example below)

Person  Project Start       End         Effort
A       P1      1/1/2015    5/31/2015   50%

A       P2      2/1/2015    3/31/2015   40%

B       P3      3/1/2015    3/31/2015   100%

B       P4      1/1/2015    2/28/2015   80%

B       P5      2/1/2015    2/28/2015   20%

---

I want to create another view that would aggregate and summarize each person's effort: for example,

Person  Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr May Jun Jul…

A       50%     90%     90%     50% 50% 0%  0%

B       100%    100%    100%    0%  0%  0%  0%

I have create a function to detect for each month: for example, for Jan column
=IF(AND([Start]>=DATE(2015,1,1),[End]>=DATE(2015,1,31)),Effort,0)

How should I loop through aggregate the data in the list for each person in each row to represent the effort for the months?

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

I am using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view that is grouped by the year of the start/end date and under that would display all the individual month items with corresponding percentage value. This could be done by creating several calculated columns to extract the year and month values from the start or end date. This would give you a more top-down view expandable/collapsable by year.

example:

+ 2005
   Adam   January   50%
   Joe      February  75%

+ 2006
   Adam   January   55%
   Joe      February  78%


Refer to this post, to extract the full month name:
http://www.sharepointboris.net/2009/05/get-the-month-name-in-calculated-column/